# What are the ssh-keygen -D and -U parameters for? How are they used with smartcards?

Tags: ssh, smartcard

The ssh-keygen manpage lists the following two parameters:

-D reader = Download the RSA public key stored in the smartcard in reader.

-U reader = Upload an existing RSA private key into the smartcard in reader.

I can't find out anything else about these after searching around.  Do they support a standard ssh_rsa keypair on a smartcard, or do they work with a pkcs11 interface and x509 formatted certificates.  Is this related to ssh certificates and able to support storing either the private signing-key or private user-key-with-certificate on a smartcard?

In short, why would I use these parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the information I was looking for on a more detailed man page.  The man page is [here (freebsd man page)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh-keygen&sektion=1).

It sounds like the -D and -U parameters talk to a pkcs11 device, and these options do indeed work with ssh certificates (via the -s parameter).  Using these it should be possible to have an offline, smartcard protected ssh ca signing key (which was my original goal).  I don't know if it is possible to have a signed user key on a smart card with this process yet.

I have not tried any of these commands yet, but I think that they are what I was looking for.  If all goes well this will allow me to setup an offline ssh ca on a yubikey neo.